# OCI8 extension for php:8.0-fpm-alpine in Dockerfile

Tags: php, linux, docker, oci8

I'm trying to install and enable OCI8 in dockerfile for php:8.0-fpm-alpine image to ..

This is a part of my Dockerfile:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.0

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine AS api_platform_php

# Install Oracle Instantclient
RUN mkdir /usr/lib/oracle
RUN apk --no-cache add libaio curl && \
    curl -o instantclient.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/217000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.7.0.0.0dbru.zip -SL && \
    curl -o instantclient-sdk.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/217000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.7.0.0.0dbru.zip -SL && \
    unzip instantclient.zip && unzip instantclient-sdk.zip &&\
    mv instantclient_21_7 /usr/lib/oracle/ && \
    rm instantclient.zip && rm instantclient-sdk.zip && \
    cd /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_21_7 \
        && ln -sf libclntsh.so.21.1 libclntsh.so \
        && ln -sf libclntshcore.so.21.1 libclntshcore.so \
        && ln -sf libocci.so.21.1 libocci.so \
        && rm -rf *.zip

#ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient
#ENV ORACLE_BASE /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient
#ENV TNS_ADMIN /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient
#ENV ORACLE_HOME /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient

# Install Oracle extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_oci --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_21_7 \
       && echo 'instantclient > /usr/lib/oracle/instantclient_21_7/' \
       && ldconfig | pecl install oci8-3.0.1 \
       && docker-php-ext-install \
               pdo_oci \
       && docker-php-ext-enable \
               oci8
```

The result is as follow :

```
(...)
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking for Oracle Database OCI8 support... yes, shared
checking PHP version... 8.0.17, ok
checking OCI8 DTrace support... no
checking size of long... 8
checking if we're at 64-bit platform... yes
configure: WARNING: OCI8 extension: ORACLE_HOME is not set, looking for default Oracle Instant Client instead
checking Oracle Instant Client directory... configure: error: Oracle Instant Client directory /usr/lib/oracle/.../client64/lib libraries not found. Try --with-oci8=instantclient,DIR
```

**configure: error: Oracle Instant Client directory /usr/lib/oracle/.../client64/lib libraries not found. Try --with-oci8=instantclient,DIR**

Thanks for your help

Comment: You might find some hints about what Alpine packages you need to install to use Instant Client in Alpine from other StackOverflow questions, but fundamentally I would never suggest using this combination - as you'll see when you find those other posts.

Answer (score 2):

I have Succeed to enable the extension... 
I think my issue was the order of the installation. 
Here the full Dockerfile :

```
# the different stages of this Dockerfile are meant to be built into separate images
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage
# https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#target


# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.0
ARG CADDY_VERSION=2

# "php" stage
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine AS api_platform_php

# persistent / runtime deps
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        acl \
        fcgi \
        file \
        gettext \
        git \
        gnu-libiconv \
    ;

# install gnu-libiconv and set LD_PRELOAD env to make iconv work fully on Alpine image.
# see https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/240#issuecomment-763112749
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so

ARG APCU_VERSION=5.1.20
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        icu-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        postgresql-dev \
        zlib-dev \
    ; \
    \
    docker-php-ext-configure zip; \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        intl \
        pdo_pgsql \
        pdo_mysql \
        zip \
        pcntl \
    ; \
    pecl install \
        apcu-${APCU_VERSION} \
    ; \
    pecl clear-cache; \
    docker-php-ext-enable \
        apcu \
        opcache \
    ; \
    \
    runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local/lib/php/extensions \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )"; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .api-phpexts-rundeps $runDeps; \
    \
    apk del .build-deps

###> recipes ###
###< recipes ###

## install Oracle Instantclient
RUN apk --no-cache add pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS} \
  && pecl install xdebug \
  && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
  && apk del pcre-dev ${PHPIZE_DEPS}

RUN apk --no-cache add php8-pear php8-dev gcc musl-dev libaio libnsl libc6-compat curl && \
cd /tmp && \
curl -o instantclient-basiclite.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip -SL && \
curl -o instantclient-sdk.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-sdk-linuxx64.zip -SL && \
unzip instantclient-basiclite.zip && \
unzip instantclient-sdk.zip && \
mv instantclient*/ /usr/lib/instantclient && \
rm instantclient-basiclite.zip && \
ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libclntsh.so.19.1 /usr/lib/libclntsh.so && \
ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libocci.so.19.1 /usr/lib/libocci.so && \
ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libociicus.so /usr/lib/libociicus.so && \
ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libnnz19.so /usr/lib/libnnz19.so && \
ln -s /usr/lib/libnsl.so.2 /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1 && \
ln -s /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 && \
ln -s /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

ENV ORACLE_BASE /usr/lib/instantclient
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/instantclient
ENV TNS_ADMIN /usr/lib/instantclient
ENV ORACLE_HOME /usr/lib/instantclient

RUN docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-oci8=instantclient,$ORACLE_HOME && docker-php-ext-install oci8
RUN docker-php-ext-configure pdo_oci --with-pdo-oci=instantclient,$ORACLE_HOME && docker-php-ext-install pdo_oci

COPY --from=composer:2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

RUN ln -s $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
COPY docker/php/conf.d/api-platform.prod.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/api-platform.ini

COPY docker/php/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf

VOLUME /var/run/php

# https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-superuser
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.composer/vendor/bin"

WORKDIR /srv/api

# build for production
ARG APP_ENV=prod

# prevent the reinstallation of vendors at every changes in the source code
COPY composer.json composer.lock symfony.lock ./
RUN set -eux; \
    composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-scripts --no-progress; \
    composer clear-cache

# copy only specifically what we need
COPY .env ./
COPY bin bin/
COPY config config/
COPY migrations migrations/
COPY public public/
COPY src src/
COPY templates templates/

RUN set -eux; \
    mkdir -p var/cache var/log; \
    composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev; \
    composer dump-env prod; \
    composer run-script --no-dev post-install-cmd; \
    chmod +x bin/console; sync
VOLUME /srv/api/var

COPY docker/php/docker-healthcheck.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-healthcheck
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-healthcheck

HEALTHCHECK --interval=10s --timeout=3s --retries=3 CMD ["docker-healthcheck"]

COPY docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint

ENV SYMFONY_PHPUNIT_VERSION=9

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]

# "caddy" stage
# depends on the "php" stage above
FROM caddy:${CADDY_VERSION}-builder-alpine AS api_platform_caddy_builder

# install Mercure and Vulcain modules
RUN xcaddy build \
    --with github.com/dunglas/mercure \
    --with github.com/dunglas/mercure/caddy \
    --with github.com/dunglas/vulcain \
    --with github.com/dunglas/vulcain/caddy

FROM caddy:${CADDY_VERSION} AS api_platform_caddy

WORKDIR /srv/api

COPY --from=api_platform_caddy_builder /usr/bin/caddy /usr/bin/caddy
COPY --from=api_platform_php /srv/api/public public/
COPY docker/caddy/Caddyfile /etc/caddy/Caddyfile
```